# Copy data from one column to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two database tables belonging to different databases, one empty and one not empty. I'm transferring data column by column to empty database table.

First I transferred names like this :

```
INSERT INTO [newdb].[dbo].[Person] (Name) 
   SELECT name
   FROM [olddb].[dbo].[members]
```

then I updated a column which is all NULL like this :

```
UPDATE [newdb].[dbo].[Person] 
SET IsApproved = 'True' 
WHERE IsApproved IS NULL
```

Now I want to update another null column in new database using the values in the old database. Can you tell me how I can carry values from old database where all cells are NULL in the new database. Thanks.

Comment: cant you copy all the columns at once in your initial insert statement? is name your primary key for both the table Person and members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is for update only :-

```
UPDATE New 
SET New.Caption = Old.Caption ,New.Created_By =Old.Created_By 
FROM [NewDB].Dbo.Product New 
JOIN [OldDB].Dbo.Product Old ON New.Id = Old.Id 
WHERE New.Is_Cos IS NULL
```

Comment: provide full name in update clause. dont use alais `New`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, Why so? to my knowledge, there shouldn't be any issue even if you use alias.

Comment: Seems that copied my answer and renamed columns

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas This is a very simple and common question with an obvious answer. I don't need to copy your solution to create an update query with a join

Comment: So you don't need to post the same answer when question already answered.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas, your solution doesn't refer different databases which is mentioned by OP.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas answers will be same you both might have think and answered same thing please dont argue here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). Could be something like that:

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as
>   there is a match between the columns in both tables.

```
UPDATE NewTable
SET N.Col = O.Col
FROM [NewDB].[dbo].[NewTable] N
INNER JOIN [OldDB].[dbo].[OldTable] O
ON N.etc = O.etc
WHERE N.Col IS NULL
```

Comment: Why do I need INNER JOIN? Thank you.

Comment: Join is used to manipulate data from 2 or more tables, you can read documentation which I provided in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question : Is .Col the column name for the desired columns? And what should I write for .etc? Thanks. And sorry for being so numb.

Comment: Yes `Col` is name for desired columns and instead of `etc` you should use column name on which tables will join (for example if exists `ID` column)

Comment: I wrote second line like this : `SET [newdb].[dbo].[Person].EMail = [olddb].[dbo].[members].email` and  I get this error : **The multi-part identifier "olddb.dbo.members.email" could not be bound.**

Comment: You need to provide correct name of databases instead of `[newdb]` and `[olddb]`

Comment: In `SET` you need to provide `ALIAS` `N` and `O` instead of all paths.